# map<vector<string>, string> giving me an error

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a map which sets a vector of string as the key and a string as the value but it keeps giving me this error:

```
invalid operands to binary expression
    ('constant Vector.....' and 'constant Vector....)
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: The way they are written `Vector<string>` suggests it's a custom class. This class needs an `operator<` to be usable an a `Map`'s key, but probably doesn't have one.

Comment: Since neither `Map` nor `Vector` are standard library classes, shall we assume they're of your own creation?

Comment: Are `Map` and `Vector` `std::map` and `std::vector` respectively? And which line is the source of the error?

Comment: @DanielFrey that should be the answer

Comment: Heh. I just learned something new from this question. @juanchopanza, has `std::vector<>` *always* had a free-function [`operator <`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) in the standard library? cppref says its pre-11.

Comment: @littleadv Made it an answer, but without further information of the class, it's hard to show the correct implementation :)

Comment: @WhozCraig why `std::vector` will need `operator <`  ?

Comment: @P0W no, `vector` does not necessarily *need* `operator<`, it *has* an `operator<`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp). If used, then it requires that the `value_type` of the vector also has an `operator<`.

Comment: @P0W because its being used as a map key. If on the off-chance the OP's code is actually using `std::map` and `std::vector`, the default comparator for strict weak ordering for a map is provided by `std::less`, which uses `operator <` on the key arguments by-default. its just interesting to me. never knew it was there before.

Comment: @WhozCraig it is in the C++03 standard, see **23.2.4**.

Answer (score 1):

The way they are written `Vector<string>` suggests it's a custom class. This class needs an `operator<` to be usable as a `Map's` key, but probably doesn't have one. You need to add

```
bool operator<( const Vector<string>& lhs, const Vector<string>& rhs )
{
    int pos = 0;
    while( true ) {
        if( pos == lhs.size() && pos == rhs.size() ) return false;
        if( pos == lhs.size() ) return true;
        if( pos == rhs.size() ) return false;
        if( lhs[ pos ] < rhs[ pos ] ) return true;
        if( rhs[ pos ] < lhs[ pos ] ) return false;
        ++pos;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `Map` is a custom class as well, we don't actually know if it requires `operator<` or something else.

Comment: @interjay Yes, but let's see what the OP replies. It is extremly likely that his `Map` *does* need `operator<`.

Comment: Map is a custom class within the library I use

Comment: so id Vector. I have called Vector previously within the code without problems

Comment: @otch92 `Vector` itself does not necessarily need `operator<`, but `Map` usually need it for it's key type, which happens to be the `Vector` here.

Comment: how would i designate this operator within the code? never used it before. Thanks

Comment: @otch92 I added a sample implementation above, based on your question's code. To test, put it somewhere in the global scope on top of the file where you get the error or just right before `createNgrams`.

Comment: Tried doing that but it didn't work. However if I was to replace Map with std::map, would it be enough to call insert to put things in that map. I tried that but it did not work.

Comment: @otch92 It's hard to help you without seeing `Map` and `Vector`. That said, I'd advice you simply use `std::map` and `std::vector`, I can't imaging those other classes are any better.